# Can initialize booking.com form 1 time but not again with ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angular-material

So I am using angular materials with angular4 and I have put html for a booking.com form inside an MdDialogue component. I want this dialogue to popup with the form inside of it when somebody pushes a button. It works as expected 1 time after the app has loaded, but not again. I would like it to work every time. There is no error message so it is unclear to me why this is happening. The logic inside booking() initializes the form.

The html for the booking.com form looks like this.

```
<ins class="bookingaff" data-aid="1179852" data-target_aid="1179846" data-prod="nsb" data-width="100%" data-height="auto">
  <!-- Anything inside will go away once widget is loaded. -->
  <a href="//www.booking.com?aid=1179846">Booking.com</a>
</ins>
```

Here is what the booking.com component looks like...

```
...
     openBookings(){
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Booking_com);
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        });
      }

      debug(data){
        console.log(data);
      }



    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'Booking_com',
      templateUrl: 'Booking_com.html',
      styleUrls: ['Booking_com.sass']
    })
    export class Booking_com implements AfterViewInit{


      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.booking();
      }

      constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<Booking_com>) {}


      booking(){
        (function(d, sc, u) {
          var s:any =  d.createElement(sc);
          var p:any =  d.getElementsByTagName(sc)[0];
          s.type = 'text/javascript';
          s.async = true;
          s.src = u + '?v=' + (+new Date());
          p.parentNode.insertBefore(s,p);
        })(document, 'script', '//aff.bstatic.com/static/affiliate_base/js/flexiproduct.js');
      }
    }
```

The images show that it works the first time but not he second time.... Any idea as to why this is happening and how to solve this issue would be great.

[image: This is working the first time when clicking the pink button]

[image: This is not working the second time when clicking the pink button]

Comment: Maybe the `Booking_com` component is instantiated only the first time you open the dialog, and not the second time around? Do you have any errors in your browser's console? What if you console.log some text in `ngAfterViewInit()`, do you see this text the second time you try to open the dialog?

Comment: No errors are thrown the second time I open the booking_com component. I  have added console.log("hello") statements before and after the booking.com logic, and those statements are executed but the html still does not render...

Comment: The same behavior occurred when using this component in a bootstrap modal, but when I place the booking.com component in a route, and route to it, then it loads every time.

Comment: *edit...it used to work every time but now it exhibits the same behavior as I am experiencing above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Examining [affiliate script](http://aff.bstatic.com/static/affiliate_base/js/flexiproduct.js) we can see, that when this script is loaded, it calls once `BookingAff.run()` function, which looks like:

```
function u() {
  if (_i_("5fc:14"), u.already_ran) return _r_();
  u.already_ran = !0;
```

it exits if `already_ran` flag is already set. So we will need to unset it on every modal open:

```
// reset already_ran flag
if (window.BookingAff && window.BookingAff.run.already_ran) {
  window.BookingAff.run.already_ran = false;
}
```

Because of these 2 reasons, booking form is rendered only once at the very first modal open.

also there is an *origin* check, which allows only *booking.com* or *bstatic.com* origins:

```
var r, i = new RegExp("(booking|bstatic).com$");
if (!e.origin.match(i)) return _r_();
```

so we cannot just run `BookingAff.run()` on each modal open from our domain.

The easiest solution would be to call `booking()` function on each modal open (of course, after resetting `already_ran` flag).

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/IlAa7XJDjQIxd6IgKXIe?p=preview

there is a JS error in my plunker saying

> ERROR Error: The selector "dialog-overview-example-dialog" did not match any elements

it comes from the original Google's example at https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog and their plunker link